# Failed to set object for CCDictionary in cocos2dx

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

I am trying to set some data(obtained from java class) to a CCDictionary then adding that dictionary object to CCArray in c++ class as below. addFriends(...) is called from native method.

```
void RecJNICommunicator::addFriends(const char * nativeStringUserName, const char * nativeStringUserId) {
CCLog(" --- inside RecJNICommunicator::addFriends --- ");

  CCDictionary * cdictionary =  CCDictionary::create();

  CCString *str1 = CCString::create(nativeStringUserName);
  CCString *str2 = CCString::create(nativeStringUserId);

  cdictionary->setObject(str1, "name");
  cdictionary->setObject(str2, "id");

  if(!FacebookFriendListScreen::friendsList) {
      CCLog(" --- FacebookFriendListScreen::friendsList is NULL... creating new --- ");
      FacebookFriendListScreen::friendsList = new CCArray;
  }
```

> // adding dictionary object to CCArray

```
  FacebookFriendListScreen::friendsList->addObject(cdictionary);

  CCLog(" --- added successfully --- ");
}
```

First time it adds successfully but later app crashes with following stack trace

```
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #00  pc 001363d2  

/data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d12CCDictionary15setObjectUnSafeEPNS_8CCObjectERKSs)
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #01  pc 00135258  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN7cocos2d12CCDictionary9setObjectEPNS_8CCObjectERKSs)
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #02  pc 000f2d9a  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (_ZN18RecJNICommunicator10addFriendsEPKcS1_)
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #03  pc 000f2c42  /data/data/com.humit/lib/libgame.so (Java_com_humit_android_HumIt_addFriends)
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #04  pc 0001ed70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
12-11 10:21:39.707: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #05  pc 0005902c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #06  pc 0005ad5c  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z22dvmResolveNativeMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #07  pc 00030bcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #08  pc 000343b0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #09  pc 0006c8c6  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z15dvmInvokeMethodP6ObjectPK6MethodP11ArrayObjectS5_P11ClassObjectb)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #10  pc 00073eba  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #11  pc 00030bcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #12  pc 000343b0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z12dvmInterpretP6ThreadPK6MethodP6JValue)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #13  pc 0006cb96  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z14dvmCallMethodVP6ThreadPK6MethodP6ObjectbP6JValueSt9__va_list)
12-11 10:21:39.712: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #14  pc 00054ff6  /system/lib/libdvm.so
12-11 10:21:39.717: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #15  pc 00049d8a  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
12-11 10:21:39.717: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #16  pc 0004b68e  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (_ZN7android14AndroidRuntime5startEPKcS2_)
12-11 10:21:39.717: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #17  pc 00008f0a  /system/bin/app_process
12-11 10:21:39.717: INFO/DEBUG(24299):          #18  pc 0001685c  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init)
```

I am quite new to c++ programming so What am I doing wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier `CCDictionary` was autorelease call and friendsList `CCArray` was static. May be because of these, memory was not getting cleared. Now I am creating `CCDictionary` using new and removed static friendsList CCArray and accessing it using class object as below. Now everything is working fine.

> creating

```
  CCDictionary * cdictionary =  new CCDictionary();

  CCString *str1 = new CCString(nativeStringUserName);
  CCString *str2 = new CCString(nativeStringUserId);

  cdictionary->setObject(str1, "name");
  cdictionary->setObject(str2, "id");

  if(facebookFriendsListscreen->friendsList != NULL && facebookFriendsListscreen->friendsInstaledList != NULL) {
      facebookFriendsListscreen->friendsList->addObject(cdictionary);
      facebookFriendsListscreen->friendsInstaledList->addObject(cdictionary);
  } else {
      CCLog(" --- CCArrays are null in addInstalledFriends --- ");
  }
```

> releasing in same method

```
  cdictionary->release();
  str1->release();
  str2->release();
```